# How to real time convert wireless packet(802.11) to Ethernet packet(802.3) in windows?

Tags: windows, network-protocols, wireless, packet, ethernet

How to real time convert wireless packet(802.11) to Ethernet packet(802.3) in windows?

I'm receive wireless packet with Wireless Lan.

I want forward this packet to Ethernet.

Can i do this work?

Comment: My Access Point is open(have not encryption)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to do network bridging. Windows has this support built in starting with XP. This will make your computer into a very expensive two port Ethernet switch (where the wireless link is a port).

If you want to do some more fancy filtering, I suggest using a [TUN/TAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TUN/TAP) driver or [`pcap`/WinPCAP](http://www.winpcap.org/), which will allow you to receive raw frames.

Comment: @M.Rezaei: Yes, you can. You can use libpcap/winpcap to receive any frames bound for your system (or overheard), but need to use a TAP device to inject a frame back into the network (which in turn will require bridging the TAP device to the physical adapter). TAP can also be used as a receive conduit (again, due to bridging).