# Why is 802.11 to 802.3 conversion impossible in monitoring mode?

Tags: wifi, wireshark, ethernet, packet-capture

When I use Wireshark to capture traffics with my wlan card with monitor mode already set, it only displays 802.11 frames. However, if I use Wireshark with managed mode wlan(promiscuous mode), it certainly displays 802.3 frames.

I searched for some related information and found out that 'network bridging' allows devices to convert 802.11 wireless packets to 802.3 packets. In case of packet capturing, pcap allows conversion.

(link: [How to real time convert wireless packet(802.11) to Ethernet packet(802.3) in windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4352166/how-to-real-time-convert-wireless-packet802-11-to-ethernet-packet802-3-in-wi))

So, Why is 802.11 to 802.3 frame conversion impossible when using monitor mode(not associated to the wireless network)?

Below are pictures of the situation. Thank you in advance.

[Promiscuous mode packet capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPePs.png)

[Monitor mode packet capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NS0lm.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For one thing, not all 802.11 packets have Ethernet equivalents; only data packets do.  In monitor mode, in addition to data packets, control and management packets can be captured - you're seeing those types of packets in your monitor-mode capture.

For another thing, when capturing in monitor mode on a "protected" network (WEP, WPA), data packets are encrypted (to protect them from being sniffed), and can't be converted to Ethernet packets until they're decrypted.  [Under some circumstances, Wireshark can decrypt them](https://wiki.wireshark.org/HowToDecrypt802.11.md), but Wireshark doesn't do any conversion from 802.11 to 802.3 in any circumstances - when not capturing in monitor mode, the 802.11 adapter converts data packets to 802.3 packets after decrypting them, and doesn't show non-data packets to the host.